# MySQL database is not executing query in my python code

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform

I have written Python code to update my MySQL database via a for loop, however when I run the code, it does not insert the data into the table. Here is my code:

```py
connection = mysql.connector.connect(\*\*db)  # \*\*

cursor = connection.cursor()

for i in range(len(alumniNames)):

    currentName = alumniNames[i]
    query = (f'INSERT INTO alumni (name, address, hometown, state, country, home_phone, mobile_phone) VALUES ("{currentName}", "{alumniInfo[currentName][2]}", "{alumniCities[i]}", "{alumniStates[i]}", "{alumniInfo[currentName][5]}", "{alumniInfo[currentName][7]}", "{alumniInfo[currentName][8]}")')
    
    values = (currentName, alumniInfo[currentName][2], alumniCities[i], alumniStates[i],
              alumniInfo[currentName][5], alumniInfo[currentName][7], alumniInfo[currentName][8])
    
    cursor.execute(query)
    print(f"Query {i + 1} Completed.")
    
    if i % 50 == 0:
        time.sleep(1)

results = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

When I run my code, no data gets inserted into the table. Also, the print statement stops at 331 (ex. "Query 331 Completed.").

I tried to googling the issue but I can't come to a conclusion as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you're probably looking for `autocommit` configuration. If you're new to python + mysql, I'd recommend checking out SQL Alchemy and Alembic; it will level up your game.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-autocommit.html
- https://www.sqlalchemy.org/
- https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org

Comment: This works, thank you! Do you know why it stops at 330 entries though?

Comment: Hmm not really. I'd set break points and examine.

Answer (score 0):

Also, just for fun you can reduce the code a bit. I use `enumerate` all - the - time! :-)

```
# instead of range+len
for i, currentName in enumerate(alumniNames):
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

try inserting

connection.commit() before connection.close()